# Bash script that takes a directory name as a command line argument!

Tags: bash, scripting, archive

Write a Bash Script that takes a directory name as a command line argument and clean the directory by removing all the files with a zero length, with a .tmp or with a .swp extension that is found in this directory.  After, create an archive of this directory, compress the archive and place it in your ~directory?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d $1 ]
then
  find -empty -print -exec rm -f {} \;
  find . -name "*.tmp" -print -exec rm -f {} \;
  find . -name "*.swp" -print -exec rm -f {} \;
  tar -zxvf $filename.tar.gz /~/ \;
else
  echo "this file is not a directory"
fi
```

Im stuck on the archive part, can you guys give me some hints!  thanks and have nice day.

Comment: The `x` flag is for eXtraction; you probably want the `c` flag for Creating an archive. You might want to read up on the `-delete` option for `find`. It's in the man page (`man find`). Actually, since it's only referencing the current directory, a simple `rm *.tmp` might be sufficient to remove files with a `.tmp` extension.

Comment: `tar` isn't the only problem, it's all sorts of messed up.

Comment: yep, "all sorts of messed up", starting with the fact that `$1` is used without double-quotes, and then not used at all in the `find` or `tar` commands.  One `find` command doesn't even specify a path, the others use `.` (the current directory, i.e. where the script was run).  `$filename` isn't double-quoted and doesn't seem to be defined anywhere, and WTF is `/~/ \;` supposed to mean?  You're also using `tar x` to extract an archive rather than `tar c` to create one.  The `echo` command is the only one you've used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

1. If this is homework, you should say so.
2. Your script only searches the current directory regardless of what directory name you give it.
3. Scripted `rm -f` in a `find` command is a really bad idea unless you really know what you're doing.
4. `\;` at the end of the `tar` command will cause an error.
5. Based on #4, you seem to be confused about the role of `;` in the `find` command.  It's passed as an argument to tell `find` where the end of the passed in command is.
6. Your `tar` command is attempting to extract from an archive, not create one.
7. Your [variables aren't quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943).
8. `/~/` will not be turned by the shell into your home directory name; that only occurs if `~` is at the start of the word.
9. If you do it right, all three of your `find` commands can be consolidated into just one command.

I'm sure there's more; that's just off the top of my head.  Poke around here on this site and you can learn an awful lot.

We're happy to help, but this is not actually a "homework help" site.  You will probably get more help if you demonstrate that *you* really want to learn, rather than just wanting to get through your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically answering the question about how to `tar` a directory - because there are several other problems with your script:

```
tar -cvzf tarfile.tgz "$1"
```

will create a gzipped tar called tarfile.tar, and put the directory from the script parameter in it.